# Laravel Entrust, query where users do not have a role

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, entrust

I would like to return all users that do not have various relationship existences, and various roles.

At the moment, this works correctly:

```
User::doesntHave('trusts')
        ->doesntHave('sites')
        ->pluck('email', 'name', 'id');
```

What I would like is to also remove users that have the 'admin' role.

So far I have tried:

```
User::doesntHave('trusts')
         ->doesntHave('sites')
         ->whereDoesntHave('roles', function ($query) {
             $query->hasRole(['admin']);
         })
         ->pluck('email', 'name', 'id')
```

But it's returning the error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::hasRole()

How can I filter out the users that have a specific role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
User::doesntHave('trusts')
         ->doesntHave('sites')
         ->whereDoesntHave('roles', function ($query) {
             $query->where('name', 'admin');
         })
         ->pluck('email', 'name', 'id')
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you @Paras.